# Как запустить линукс шелл программу с несколькими агрументами из питона?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Как запустить `linux shell` программу с несколькими аргументами из питона? Пробовал `os`, `subprocess`, неясно как ввести аргументы. Программа [BBMap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbmap/).

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['программа', 'аргумент 1', 'argument 2'])
```

код запускает `программа` из `$PATH`, передавая ей `аргумент 1` в качестве первого аргумента и `argument 2` в качестве второго аргумента. Если `программа` завершается с ошибкой (не нулевой возвращаемый код), то `check_call()` выбрасывает исключение.

Каждый элемент списка это отдельный аргумент. Shell неявно не используется поэтому мета-символы такие как пробелы не разбивают аргументы или например `$a` не нужно экранировать.

Если `программа` это shell скрипт, то необходимо добавить соответствующий shebang, например, `#!/bin/sh` в самом начале файла и сделать скрипт исполняемым: `chmod +x программа`. Чтобы не указывать путь к `программа`, файл должен лежать в одной из директорий, указанных в `$PATH` переменной окружения (`echo $PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

судя по [приведённым примерам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/4827341), так и пишите, как в командной строке (в случае `os.system`):

```
os.system("программа опция1 опция2 аргумент1 аргумент2 ...")
```

Comment: `os.system()` всегда запускает shell, что не нужно в большинстве случаев. Используйте `subprocess` как показано в принятом ответе из вашей ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) принимает первым параметром список аргументов, необходимых для запуска скрипта.

Стоит отметить, что метод `run` появился начиная с версии Python 3.5. Если необходима поддержка ранних версий, вы можете воспользоваться методом [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess


def main():
    print('subprocess.run:')
    print(subprocess.run(["bash", "example.bs", "1", "2", "42"]))
    print()

    print('subprocess.call:')
    print(subprocess.call(["bash", "example.bs", "1", "2", "42"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*example.bs*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $@
```

Результат:

```
$ ./main.py
subprocess.run:
1 2 42
CompletedProcess(args=['bash', 'example.bs', '1', '2', '42'], returncode=0)

subprocess.call:
1 2 42
0
```

Comment: не нужно дополнительный `bash` запускать. Даже в вашем примере, скрипт имеет shebang. Чтобы запустить `./example` исполняемый скрипт (`chmod +x example`), можно вызвать: `subprocess.check_call('./example 1 2 42'.split())`

Comment: Можно и не использовать bash, да. Но чтобы не задумываться о том, не забыли ли мы навесить на файл `-x`, особенно если идет выполнение файла из другого скрипта, предпочитаю явно указывать интерпретатор.

Comment: неверный подход. Не нужно случайные файлы с диска как bash-скрипт пытаться выполнить. Если файл должен быть исполняемым, то он должен иметь соответствующие настройки.

Comment: Не согласен. С чего вы взяли, что это случайные файлы?

Comment: Если файл неслучайный, то есть заранее известно что он будет запускаться как скрипт, то такой файл имеет разрешение на исполнение и вызывать `bash` излишне.